# adding jpg to a variable

Tags: php, xml, variables, xml-parsing

I am creating a variable from an XML file ($image) and I need to create a new variable that combines $image with '.jpg'. I've tried:

`$image = $record->getElementsByTagName( "name_id" );
  echo $image.".jpg";
  $image = $image->item(0)->nodeValue;`

But this doesn't add .jpg to the variable in the script. The reason I need to do this is the XML file doesn't have the jpg file extension only the image reference as a sequence of numbers. Any ideas?

Comment: What is `$image`? Is it an object, a string, an array?

Comment: Is that echo not supposed to come at the end?

Comment: This code is of little use :|

Answer (score 0):

If `$image` is a string, just concoct the strings together with `.`.
You can see this as an example:

```
<?php
   $img = hello;
   $imgfinal = $img . ".jpg";
   echo $img;
?>
```

As expected the output is `hello.jpg`. Hope this helped.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for:

```
$image = $record->getElementsByTagName( "name_id" );
$image = $image->item(0)->nodeValue;
$image = $image . ".jpg";
```

Now $image should contain the filename with the file extension